# Linking Data in multiple Charts Highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts, drilldown

I'm new to JS charting libraries and I have started working with Highcharts. I have a scenario like this and I couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Scenario: I have a bar chart showing the employee turn over by years. Also, I have a  separate pie chart showing different department's percentage of turnover. But when I click on one year (one column on bar graph ) the pie chart should get changed to show the employee turnover by different departments only for that selected year.

I searched in different places and I couldn't get a solution for this. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could be many reasons, so please try to produce the minimal working example of this problem and provide me with it (or just the code)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem, you just need to link the of xAxis or yAxis with series like below:

```
yAxis:{
  id: 'voltage-axis', // ====This is the thing you need
  title: {
        text: 'Voltage'
     },
  max:250,
  min:0,
  lineWidth: 2,
  lineColor: '#08F',
  opposite: true
 } 
series: [{
    yAxis: 'voltage-axis', // Link here that yAxis id
    name: 'Rainfall',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 
     95.6, 54.4],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' mm'
    }

}
```

Change the code as per your requirement. I hope this will help you.